# Migrate oracle to mysql

Tags: mysql, oracle

I am trying to migrate oracle to mysql.

Question 1.

```
Instr('aa bb cc', ' ', -1,1)
```

I changed it

```
CHAR_LENGTH('aa bb cc') - LOCATE(' ', REVERSE('aa bb cc'))+1
```

both return

```
6
```

But I don't know how to make query with

```
Instr('aa bb cc', ' ', -1, 2)
```

Question 2.

This is oracle query.

```
CASE WHEN Regexp_like(
REPLACE(SUBSTR(TRIM(col), INSTR(TRIM(col), ' ', -1,1), 
                                                        (LENGTH(TRIM(col)) - INSTR(TRIM(col), ' ',-1, 1))
 + 1), ' ',
 ''),
 '[0-9|0-9\-]') THEN
REPLACE(SUBSTR(TRIM(col), INSTR(TRIM(col), ' ', -1, 2),
 (INSTR(TRIM(col), ' ', -1, 1) - INSTR(TRIM(col), ' ', -1, 2)
) +
 1), ' ', '') END
```

How to change the query to mysql query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL also has instr() function, however it has less feature than Oracle

```
ora :: Instr('aa bb cc', ' ', -1, 1) == 
my  :: length('aa bb cc') - length(substring_index('aa bb cc', ' ', -1))

ora :: Instr('aa bb cc', ' ', -1, 2) == 
my  :: length('aa bb cc') - length(substring_index('aa bb cc', ' ', -2))
```

MySQL also uses (so there is no need to change):

```
CASE WHEN value THEN do-something END
```

MySQL replace:

```
REPLACE(str, from, to)
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_replace
```

Other issue should be all same.

Regexp_like

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/conditions018.htm

```
regexp(source_string, pattern, match_parameter)
```

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html

```
source_string REGEXP pattern
```

Answer (score 0):

As a Research you can use INSTR in MYSQL like:

```
Set @col  = "sample";
select INSTR(@col,"le")
```

You can refer this [INSTR()](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/string-functions/mysql-instr-function.php)

Getting the length by removing spaces:

```
select LENGTH((replace(@col," ","")))
```